# How many days before work permit expiry, we should travel to Canada in order to apply for extension without any problem?

Tags: working-visas, immigration, canada

I have a Canada work permit which is going to expire by august, how many days before work permit expiry i should travel to Canada in order to apply for extension without any problem ?

Comment: Why are you not in Canada? How long have you been outside the country?

Comment: I am an IT professional, as i could not find projects through my employer i did not get a chance to travel till now

Comment: Are there any conditions on your work permit that you’ve not fulfilled, given it seems you’ve not used it? http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=169&top=17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/work-canada/permit/temporary/extend.html

http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=474&top=17

"You should apply at least 30 days before your current status expires if you want to extend your stay as a worker in Canada."

Comment: Thanks C'est Moi